# Is it possible to edit the git hash code?

Tags: git, github, hash

I was just wondering if there was a way to specify the hash code that is generated by Git when you do a commit.

i.e

git commit -m "message"

github has the commit message and the hash code and we use the hash code for referencing the commit. Is it possible to use the commit message or edit the hash code to something that could be more recognisable when referencing the commit.

Cheers

Comment: A hash is a representation of the commit. You can change it by amending the commit, but you cannot specify one yourself. that is not what a hash is for

Comment: Maybe [vanityhash](http://www.finnie.org/software/vanityhash/) or something like it could be adapted for git

Comment: And here's the "something like it": https://github.com/bradfitz/gitbrute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that would defeat one of the goals of git - that the hash code is based on the contents of the commit and previous commits which can later be verified against changes. You could create a tag to refer to a commit with the tag name being a string, making it easier to reference the commit. See [git tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)